# Using Linq Select to create a list that contains more items than the original list

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I have a list of items. For example (although the list could be any length):

```
var inputList = new List<Input1>()
{
    new Input1() { Test = "a" },
    new Input1() { Test = "b" }
};
```

What I want to do is create a new list of:

```
 a1, a2, b8, b9
```

That is the value of `Test` (i.e. a) with a suffix based on the value of `Test`.

In that order. Obviously, this is a minimum workable example, not the actual problem. So I'd like to use something like the `.Select` to split the data - something like this:

```
        var outputList = inputList.Select(x =>
        {
            if (x.Test == "a")
            {
                return new Input1() { Test = "a1" };
                //return new Input1() { Test = "a2" };
            }
            else if (x.Test == "b")
            {
                return new Input1() { Test = "b8" };
                //return new Input1() { Test = "b9" };
            }
            else
            {
                return x;
            }
        });
```

`Input1` for completeness:

```
class Input1
{
    public string Test { get; set; }
}
```

That is, to return a list that contains items that were not in the original list.

I realise I can use a `foreach`, but I'm interested if there's a better / more concise way.

Comment: What is `Input1`? What is `a1, a2, b8, b9`? How `1`, `2`, `8` and `9` appears in it? Commented lines (with `a1` and `b9`) does't help to understand the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose you have a method that transforms your single input into multiple inputs:

```
public static Input1[] Transform(Input1 x)
{
    if (x.Test == "a") return new[] {new Input1("a1"), new Input1("a2")};
    if (x.Test == "b") return new[] {new Input1("b8"), new Input1("b9")};
    return new[] {x};
}
```

(This is just from your toy example - I guess you actually need a transformation that is more meaningful.)

Then you can just use `SelectMany` to get your desired result in the correct order:

```
inputList
    .SelectMany(Transform);
```

Comment: This is a good answer to the question, but the issue that I have is that `inputList` can be any length

Comment: @stannage That doesn't matter. `SelectMany` maps every single item of your list into a sequence of items, and flattens them. You just need to define your mapping.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using C# 8.0 or above, you may use [switch expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/switch-expression) as follows:

```
var outputList =
    inputList.SelectMany(x => x.Test switch
    {
        "a" => new[] { new Input1() { Test = "a1" }, new Input1() { Test = "a2" } },
        "b" => new[] { new Input1() { Test = "b8" }, new Input1() { Test = "b9" } },
        _ => new[] { x }
    })
    .ToList();
```